# Difference between iPod and iPhone? in APNS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ipod-touch

I develop a App with Push Notifications, but I have one Problem, at my iPhone he will sent the Devicetoken, but on my iPod 5. Gen I got an error...

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment'
>   entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x1652a050
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string
>   found for application}

can someone explain me why? :(

Comment: looks your build setting option is not correctly

Comment: This issue generally faced when we build an application with application identifier (app id) which is not enabled for push notification. Please check

Answer (score 0):

As `TechNet` mentioned in comments, your app must be installed with a bundle-identifier for which APNS has been activated (on `iTunesConnect`.)  As far as APNS is concerned, there is no difference between your iPhone, iPod or iPad (any of the variations.)  The error message "*no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application*" specifically refers to the provisioning profile used on the device, and the bundle-identifier not being authorized for APNS.  To check:

- Log in to iTunesConnect and make sure you've turned on APNS for this bundle-ID.  (Since it works on  your phone, you probably have.  But check, anyway.)
- Make sure you have a provisioning profile that specifies it is for this bundle-ID (*i.e.*, not a wildcard profile.)
- Make sure that this provisioning profile is installed on the desired device (in this case, your iPod.)
- Make sure that your build settings are set to sign the app with this profile when installing the app.

(As a guess, I'd say that the problem is almost certainly the build settings selecting the wrong profile.)